# Yolov8 results: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'path'- attributes not found

Tags: csv, save, predict, inference, yolov8

I am working in colab with a Yolov8 object detection model. The code runs through the image subfolders correctly and the model is outputting correct results in the terminal, however I am unable to get results in a useable format after this point.

```
!pip install ultralytics
import ultralytics
from ultralytics import YOLO
import pandas as pd
import os

# Mount Google Drive to access local files
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Set model details
model = YOLO('/content/drive/MyDrive/train/weights/best.pt')

# Set path to the parent folder containing image subfolders
parent_folder = "/content/drive/MyDrive"

# Create an empty list to store the results
results_list = []

for image_file in image_files:
    # Set path to image file
    path_to_image = os.path.join(path_to_folder, image_file)

    # Predict using the model and get the bounding box coordinates
    results = model.predict(path_to_image, conf=0.8, classes=1, boxes=True,)
    
    # Extract information from  results
    image = results.path
    xyxy = results.xyxy
    conf = results.probs

    # Append the extracted information to the list
    results_list.append([image, xyxy, conf])
    
# Create a pandas DataFrame from the results list
df = pd.DataFrame(results_list, columns=['image', 'xyxy', 'conf'])

# Save the DataFrame as a CSV file
df.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/1.predictions/object_detection_results.csv', index=False)
```

I have tried getting things into a json, txt or csv format but can't get extract any of the variables needed, mainly xyxy.

For the use case, it is important to get:

1. the image name
2. bounding box dimensions
3. confidence interval

ideally as separate columns, and one row per prediction.

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-bac2882f463a> in <cell line: 20>()
     26 
     27     # Extract information from  results
---> 28     imagename = results.path
     29     boxes = results.boxes
     30     probs = results.probs

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'path'
```

The same error occurs for boxes / probs and xyxy.

However I checked the documentation and 'path' / 'boxes' and 'probs' seem to be the correct attributes.

At a loss here, any advice to get a semi useable format would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `results` here is a **list** of *ultralytics.engine.results.Results* class objects, a class for storing and manipulating inference results. Each object in this list represents result information for every image in a source. As you pass to the model a single image at a time, you can refer to the [0] index of this list to get all the needed information.

`xyxy` and `conf` are **`boxes`** properties, they are both stored as *torch.Tensor*, but you can translate them to lists for convenience.

```
image = results[0].path
xyxy = results[0].boxes.xyxy.tolist()
conf = results[0].boxes.conf.tolist()
```

More information about working with results [here](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#working-with-results).